# Set IIS 7 to listen to different port than 80

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I know it can be done for each of the site hosted but Can IIS's default port be set to a different one?

Answer (score 22):

From the IIS management console, select `Default Web Site`. On the right-hand side, click the `Edit Bindings` link and in the subsequent dialog, change the default port binding as desired.

Comment: But this will be for *that* specific site ONLY. What if I want it global. Say IIS needs to listen ONLY to port 8080? Thank you though!

Comment: IIS is nothing more than a collection of sites. Each site has bindings that are set up for it when it is created. I haven't come across a way to make a binding apply to all sites within IIS. Using scripting, probably PowerShell, you should be able to enumerate all sites and adjust their bindings as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution. My router was allowing traffic in correctly but Windows Firewall was not allowing traffic in on Port 80. I had to allow it by enabling the rule.